# Mongo keeps crashing after upgrading 3.4 to 3.6

Tags: mongodb

I upgraded Mongo from 3.4 to 3.6 and the process keeps crashing. This is on OSX Catalina. 
I upgraded by copying the new binaries and running: `db.adminCommand({setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.6"})`

The following are the logs when mongo crashes (it mentions downgrading, which is not what I did):

```
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] WiredTiger error
> (24) [1583324657:111204][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server:
> __directory_list_worker, 48: /Users/sb/data/db/journal: directory-list: opendir: Too many open files Raw:
> [1583324657:111204][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server:
> __directory_list_worker, 48: /Users/sb/data/db/journal: directory-list: opendir: Too many open files
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] An unsupported
> journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback from version
> 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] WiredTiger error
> (24) [1583324657:111306][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server:
> __log_prealloc_once, 469: log pre-alloc server error: Too many open files Raw: [1583324657:111306][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server:
> __log_prealloc_once, 469: log pre-alloc server error: Too many open files 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] An
> unsupported journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback
> from version 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut
> it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] WiredTiger error
> (24) [1583324657:111342][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server:
> __log_server, 1015: log server error: Too many open files Raw: [1583324657:111342][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server: __log_server,
> 1015: log server error: Too many open files
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] An unsupported
> journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback from version
> 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] WiredTiger error
> (-31804) [1583324657:111424][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server:
> __wt_panic, 523: the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic Raw:
> [1583324657:111424][6354:0x7000048fc000], log-server: __wt_panic, 523:
> the process must exit and restart: WT_PANIC: WiredTiger library panic
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 E STORAGE  [thread234] An unsupported
> journal format detected - If you are trying to rollback from version
> 4.0 to 3.6, please re-start a 4.0 binary and cleanly shut it down so that the journal format will be downgraded.
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 F -        [thread234] Fatal Assertion
> 50853 at src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_util.cpp 419
> 2020-03-04T12:24:17.111+0000 F -        [thread234]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `Too many open files` was the issue. I added the following to `.bash_profile`: `ulimit -n 2048`, sourced bash profile and then restarted Mongo with no further issues.